# How do you remove nodes from a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a linked linked of student objects.  It's basically a database that stores data about students as student objects.  The only problem I am having is creating the `removeStudent` method. Posted below is what I have tried so far, altering different parts of it to see if a different result occurs.  Right now with this code, I can delete a student in my driver, but it will also delete every student before the one that I want to delete as well, leaving behind only the students that are in the database after the student that I am trying to delete.

```
public void RemoveElements(Object Student) {

    LinearNode<Object> current = element;
    LinearNode<Object> temp = current;




    while (current.getNext()  != null) {

        temp = current;
        current = current.getNext();


        if(current.getElement() == Student) {


        temp.setNext(current.getNext());
        length--;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: He's "hidden it" in the question title: "How to remove nodes from a linked list" (Found it after 5 min of searching)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void RemoveElements(Object Student) {

    LinearNode<Object> current = element;
    LinearNode<Object> previous = null;
    //LinearNode<Object>(student);



    while (current.getNext()  != null) {

        current = current.getNext();


        if(current.getElement() == Student) {

            length--;
            element = element.getNext();
            if (previous != null) { 
               previous.setNext(element.getNext();
            } else {
               //if you have a pointer to the head element place it element.getNext();
            }


        }
        previous = current;
    }

}
```

Comment: don't do homework for people.  Guide them so they understand.

Comment: I didn't check for end of list either so this won't totally work but good point..

Comment: +1 for not doing others' homework.  Code is better understood than blindly added to a project.

Answer (score 0):

If the current contains the object to be removed, you need get a reference to the previous node, and point it at the next node.  So you have

`A -> B -> C`

and B contains the item to be removed, you want your linked list to look like

`A -> C`

A few things are wrong with your code

1)  You are not doing the above
2)  You are not setting previous within your while loop.  You can do that right before

`current = current.getNext();`

3) For the code

`LinearNode<Object> current = element;`

at the top, what is `element`?

Comment: element is the head of the list.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `element` is the head of the list.  Look at the code that changes `element` and change it so that when you delete the second item, `element` still points to the first `element` and the first element points to the third instead of the second.

Comment: i got it. i uncommented the previous.setNext string and set previous equal to current. it works now. thanks anyway lol

Comment: i also changed the LinearNode<Object> previous to temp because it seemed to make more sense that way.